# Query to check whether the id exists in a table or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working on SQL Server 2008.

Following is my query,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Usp_Travelready_Admin_AddUser        
  (        
     @pLoggedUserId AS INT,
     @pMappedUser AS INT
   )        
AS        
BEGIN  
   SET NOCOUNT ON  

   IF EXISTS  
   ( 
      INSERT INTO TESTUSER (Var_LoggedInUser, Var_MappedUSer)        
      VALUES (@pLoggedUserId, @pMappedUser)
   )
   ELSE
   (
      UPDATE TESTUSER   
      SET Var_MappedUSer = @pMappedUser 
      WHERE Var_LoggedInUser = @pLoggedUserId
   )

   SET NOCOUNT OFF             
END
```

where TestUser table contains 2 columns `Var_MappedUSer` and `Var_LoggedInUser` I want to write a stored procedure to update the `Var_MappedUSer` if `Var_LoggedInUser` already exists in the table and insert user if it is not available in the table

What mistake did I make in above stored procedure?

Comment: you can first check about the existence of the user in table, by `count(*)` value from table with condition on var_loggedInUser column.
if user exists then update else simply  insert.

Comment: @pratikgarg: but using `IF EXISTS()` is usually **much preferred** and can be significantly faster than using `COUNT(*)` ...

Comment: This is also a good case example for MERGE, you might want to check into that to get optimal results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Exists` check if query returned any result so do this:

```
IF EXISTS (select * from TESTUSER where Var_LoggedInUser = @pLoggedUserId)
begin
  INSERT INTO TESTUSER (Var_LoggedInUser, Var_MappedUSer)
  VALUES (@pLoggedUserId, @pMappedUser)
end
ELSE
begin
  UPDATE TESTUSER   
  SET Var_MappedUSer = @pMappedUser 
  WHERE Var_LoggedInUser = @pLoggedUserId
end
```

Also using parenthesis to group operations between `if.. else` is invalid, you have to use `begin .. end` syntax.